# viewWillAppear in viewcontrollers of a tabbar

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, viewwillappear

In my tab-bar I have four viewcontrollers, and what happens in one can affect the view of the other, so I may need to reload some elements in the viewcontroller when it becomes visible. Normally I'd fix that by implementing viewWillAppear, but when I switch between the tabs, viewWillAppear does not seem to get called. How can I fix that, or what should I do instead?

Update: as a PS I should add that this is a tabbarcontroller in a navigationcontroller hierarchy

Cheers

Nik

Comment: I'm not sure it is same problem... but might worth to loot

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/131062/iphone-viewwillappear-not-firing/8157562#8157562

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`viewWillAppear` should only be used when the view appears, and not for updating it.

Use `setNeedsDisplay` on the `viewController`'s view instead.

Comment: Where would I call setNeedsDisplay from? The problem is that I need a hook for when the user chooses a new viewcontroller from the tabbar

Comment: Oh, sory, I mixed up things here a little bit.
I'm not sure why the viewWillAppear is not getting called, but I know a way around it:

Make some object a tabBarController delegate, and it will the send the message, that a new view was selected, and call view will appear from there.

Comment: Sounds like an interesting idea, I'll give that a try tomorrow :-)

Answer (score 10):

You may use the tabbar controller delegate works like a charm

```
-(void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    [viewController viewWillAppear:YES];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please see my answer here

[iPhone viewWillAppear not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/131062/iphone-viewwillappear-not-firing/6833875#6833875)

Answer (score 1):

And in case you find this question because you would like to update something in the `UITabBarController` itself, not the `UIViewControllers` of a `UITabBarController`, like the OP's question. For example, hiding or displaying a custom `UITabBarButton`. In Swift 3.0 overriding `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate` of my `UITabBarController` class worked for me.

```
override func setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate() {

}
```