# hidesBottomBarWhenPushed and a pushy UISearchBar on short UITableViews

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm working on an application that has a view hierarchy that is very similar to Apple's Music or iPod aps. It has a UITabBarController containing UINavigationControllers presenting UITableViews that eventually lead to a UIViewController that sets `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` to `YES` in its designated initializer (to hide the UITabBar). The previous UITableViews all have a UISearchBar in their `tableHeaderView` that I move out of sight in `viewWillAppear:`.

The UISearch normally remains hidden until pulled down except when backing out of the UIView to a short UITableView. It remains hidden through the UITableView's `viewWillAppear:` and `viewDidAppear:` methods and the UIView's `viewWillDisappear:` and `viewDidDisappear:` methods and then finally pops down of its own accord. If I comment out `self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;` in the UIView the UISearchBar stays hidden when backing out of that view.

What is causing the UITableView to reveal the UISearchBar after I have hidden it? Is there a delegate method higher up in the view hierarchy that I can use to prevent it from happening?

---

**Update** I've created a simple project with the minimum amount of code needed to reproduce the problem. Download [PushySearchBar.zip](http://shauninman.com/assets/downloads/PushySearchBar.zip). (Sorry, I had a mod_rewrite rule preventing downloads from third-party domains. I've added Stack Overflow to the whitelist. Download should work now.)

Comment: Take a look at my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/45956456/2774520

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the `UISearchBar` have text in it when backing out of the `UIViewController`? Seems plausible that this might cause it to be displayed by default.

**EDIT**: (adding below comment to body of answer for easier scanning / finding, plus adding some explanation.)

Duplicate your `viewWillAppear:` method body in `viewDidAppear:` in `SearchableTableViewController`. This fixes the issue in my testing.

Basically, all this does is ensure that the offset is set correctly on either side of the navigation animation.

Comment: Nope. Just the default "Search" placeholder that doesn't cause it to pop-down on any of the preceding views.

Comment: Another theory: Could the `UITableView` be resizing itself to as the `UITabView` is being slid back in, causing the `contentOffset` to change? That seems far fetched, but if you could `NSLog` or `po` the offset before and after, you might find the culprit.

Comment: It's possible but the change is happening after all of the view lifecycle methods fire so part of the problem is figuring out where to place the `NSLog()` for the "after" check.

Comment: You could subclass `UITableView` and override `setContentOffset:` (and `setContentOffset:animated:`) to add a breakpoint or `NSLog`, then use that tableView in place of the default. This would allow you to see the backtrace.

Comment: Here you go: Duplicate your `viewWillAppear:` method body in `viewDidAppear:` in `SearchableTableViewController`. This fixes the issue in my testing.

Comment: Good call. Looks like the private `[UIScrollView(Static) _adjustContentOffsetIfNecessary]` is the last method to call `setContentOffset:` before the jump occurs. Looks like it's sending a `-0.0` as the y value which after initial testing seems to be a unique value that I can use to return from the method without calling the super to eliminate the problem. I might have my answer.

Comment: Nope. That breaks tapping the status bar to scroll to top.

Answer (score 0):

Shaun - I'm still learning Objective-C too so I might be off on this, but I think the issue is that `ViewWillAppear:` fires once when you get to the SearchableTableView 3 view, and then when you try to go backwards from Terminal to SearchableTableView 3 it's not firing again.  I duplicated the code in `ViewWillAppear:` and put it in `ViewDidAppear:` and the search bar appears to be hiding properly.

**UPDATE:** This post seems to verify the above and offer cleaner solutions: [iPhone viewWillAppear not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/131062/iphone-viewwillappear-not-firing)

Comment: Thanks Jon but the problem isn't that the UITableView's `viewWillAppear:` isn't firing when backing out of the UIView. The problem is that some event after that method fires is forcing its contentOffset back to `(0,0)` and causing the UISearchBar (which *is* moved offscreen successfully in the returning UITableView's `viewWillAppear:`) to pop back into view.