# UISearchBar jumps if pushed controller hides the tab bar

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uisearchbar

My UI structure is as follow:

`UITabBarController` (**TBC**) -> `UINavigationController` (**NC**) -> `UITableViewController` (**TVC**)

(for the simplicity of the example lets say the **TBC** has only one controller on its `viewControllers` array - the **NC**)

My **TVC** has `UISearchBar` as its table header, and when the **TVC** appear I hide the search bar beneath the **NC** navigation bar by settings the table view content offset.

When user tap a cell in the **TVC** another view controller is pushed (**VC**) and hides the tab bar with `VC.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;`

Now there is a very annoying behavior that I dont know how to solve:
When the user tap the back button from **VC** back to **TVC**, the search bar jumps to be visible even if it was hidden (beneath the navigation bar) before the **VC** was pushed.

This effect happens only if the **TVC** doesn't have enough rows to fill the screen, its like the search bar force itself to be visible if there is a place on screen. but its really looks bad and buggy.

I uploaded a [simple project](https://onedrive.live.com/?gologin=1&mkt=en-US#cid=A058C132E2551E56&id=A058C132E2551E56!105) that demonstrates the problem, it has the same structure as I described in my question.
I added two bar buttons for your convenience, the "hide bar" button hides the search bar for you, and the "toggle count" button toggle the table view rows count to demonstrate that the issue happens only if there are few items.

Comment: video/sample project will help (i know it's simple to recreate but can help narrow down the possible solutions)

Comment: @staticVoidMan i updated my question with an example project.

Comment: hm... weird indeed and when you select the searchBar and while the keyboard is on screen and you push and pop back, the searchbar comes even lower. ... lets c

Comment: @Eyal your problem solved check my solution

Comment: simple logic why you are breaking yours head

Comment: @Eyal check my update answer and sample project

Comment: Bug is still not fixed as of iOS 9.3

Answer (score 7):

Okay.. It looks to me like you've stumbled upon a bug. It should be reported through apples bugreporter ([here](http://bugreport.apple.com)).

I've made a fairy simple working work-around, but keep in mind that it **is** a work-around. This will work, but you might have to review it if you have/add other controls to the tableView. It should be safe to use(not acting randomly), and it's not the ugliest of work-arounds, so I think it's fine to use in a release. I've uploaded the same **project with the fix [here](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=BCF0BE0BC3941E55!423&authkey=!APTwynLss3_eeZI&ithint=folder,.zip)**, and you can just go ahead and download it, and you'll probably understand what I've done. I'll explain (in extreme detail) what I've actually thought and done here, in case the download links dies in the future:

**Train of thought:**

As simalone also said, the problem is that when `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` is set to `YES`, then it will call an additional `viewDidLayoutSubviews` which somehow resets your current state. We need to override `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, and check if we are laying out subviews **because** we are coming from `ViewController`, or if it's just a regular call. When we establish that the call is indeed because we are returning from `ViewController`, we need to hide the search bar (only if it was hidden before).

When we return from `ViewController`, three calls are made to `viewDidLayoutSubviews` in `TableViewController`. I'm guessing the first is for `tableView`, and it seems that the second call is 'for'(or rather *from*) the tabBar. This second one is the one moving the `searchBar` down. I have no idea what the third call is, but we can ignore it.

So now there are three things we need to check inside `viewDidLayoutSubviews`: We need to check if we are returning from `ViewController`, we need to check if the searchBar was hidden before we pushed(if it should hidden be now), and we need to check that it's the **second** call to this method.

First things first.

In `TableViewController`, I added a property `@property BOOL backPush;` to the header(`.h`)-file. Now I need to change this variable from `ViewController`.

In `ViewController`, I put this:

```
#import "TableViewController"
...
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    if(self.isMovingFromParentViewController)
    {
        if([self.navigationController.topViewController isKindOfClass:[TableViewController class]])
            [((TableViewController*)self.navigationController.topViewController) setBackPush:YES];
    }
}
```

In the code above, when the view is disappearing (I.E pushing forward, back, closing, whatever), I'm checking if we are disappearing because it was removed from the parent. If it is(which it is when the back-button is called), I check if the **now**-current top view controller is of class `TableViewController`, which it also is if we go back. Then I set the property `backPush` to `YES`. That's the only thing we need in `ViewController`.

Now, to the `TableViewController`. I added a *counter* next to your row-count:

```
@interface TableViewController () {
    NSInteger _rows;
    int count;
}
```

This is to keep track of how many calls have been made to `viewDidLayoutSubviews` later. I set `count = 0;` in `viewDidLoad`.

Now to the magic:

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    if((self.backPush && count == 0 && self.tableView.contentOffset.y == 
                    self.tableView.tableHeaderView.frame.size.height) || 
                    (self.backPush && count == 1 && 
                    self.tableView.contentOffset.y == 0))
    {
        if(count == 0)
            count++;
        else
        {
            count = 0;
            self.backPush = NO;
            [self hideSearchBar];
        }
    }
    else if((count == 0 || count == 1) || self.tableView.tableHeaderView.isFirstResponder)
    {
        count = 0;

        self.backPush = NO;
    }
}
```

The first if-statement wants either of these situations:

1. `backPush` is `YES`, `count` is `0`, and searchBar is already hidden.
2. `backPush` is `YES`, `count` is `1`, and searchBar is visible.

If 1. is true, then we increment `count` by 1.
If 2. is true, then 1. has already happened, and we now know that we are in the second round of `viewDidLayout..` when we are coming back from **VC** AND that the searchBar **WAS** hidden (because 1. happened) but now isn't hidden. It probably happens in the super-method or something.
Now we can finally push the searchBar out again. I also reset count and set backPush back to `NO`.

The `else if` is also pretty important. It checks if `count` is `0` or `1`, or if the searchBar has the keyboard showing. If count is `0` or `1` when it reaches here, it means that the first if-statement failed, e.g that the searchBar wasn't hidden, or that it was scrolled far up.

(When I think of it, the else-if should check if `backPush` is `YES` as well. Now it sets those variables repeatedly)

Let me know if you find a better way!

Comment: thank you for your detailed answer but that looks like a very big workaround so I prefer to avoid it for now, +1 for your effort

Comment: @Eyal I agree, but the problem seems to be a bug, so this is the only way I can think of as a temporary fix. You should report it to Apple's bugreporter. Or did you find another solution?

Answer (score 2):

I think this one is simple solution. Thanks to 
[Sti](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1203228/sti)

for giving some ideas to solve this bug.

Initialize variable `var hideSearchBar = false`

and inside viewDidLayoutSubviews add this code for maintain same content offset.

```
if hideSearchBar == true {
    self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0,  self.tableView.tableHeaderView!.bounds.height - self.tableView.contentInset.top)
}
```

Finally implement below methods.

```
override func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if self.tableView.tableHeaderView!.bounds.height - self.tableView.contentInset.top == self.tableView.contentOffset.y && self.tableView.dragging == false {
        hideSearchBar = true
    }
    else if self.tableView.dragging == true {//Reset hiding process after user dragging
        hideSearchBar = false
    }
}

func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    if self.tableView.contentOffset.y + self.tableView.contentInset.top <= self.tableView.tableHeaderView!.bounds.height
    {
        self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, self.tableView.tableHeaderView!.bounds.height - self.tableView.contentInset.top)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to set for TVC

```
 self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem caused by `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES` , if you uncheck `Hide Bottom Bar On Push`,  the searchBar will not appear when VC back to TVC.

Try this in TableViewController.m:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    [self hideSearchBar];
}
```

I can't explain why but I know that if `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES` for UITabBarController to push vc,  `viewDidLayoutSubviews` will be called more than once when the view appears again. First time subviews keep the same position, whereas the second time be called, subviews will be adjusted for some reason to relayout with the most original position, which is very weird. Do your custom layout in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` will prevent this to happen even after `viewDidAppear`.

Comment: this will block the user from showing the search bar completely

Comment: @Eyal what you should do `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is depended on yourself. Here just a example how to control search bar appearance, you can save the appearance in `viewDidDisappear`,  then restore it in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` after `viewDidAppear`.

Answer (score 0):

[UITableViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) always modifies its UITableviews content offset in its viewDidAppear to make sure that its all rows are visible. So your hacky methods don't work here.

There are several solution to this problem. The one I selected is shown below

First delete that searchBar from your storyboard.

```
@interface TableViewController () {
    NSInteger _rows;
}

@end

@implementation TableViewController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _rows = 4; // +1 for searchBar

}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (void)hideSearchBar {
    // hide search bar
    [[self tableView] scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndex:1] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];
}

- (IBAction)toggleCount:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {
    if (_rows == 20) {
        _rows = 4;
    } else {
        _rows = 20;
    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (IBAction)hideBar:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {
    [self hideSearchBar];
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return _rows;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    if(indexPath.row == 0){
        UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil];
        UISearchBar *searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width,44)];
        [cell addSubview:searchBar];
        return cell;
    }

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.textLabel.text = @"cell";

    return cell;
}

@end
```

The above solution just ensures that automatic scrolling magic is disabled.

If you want your default searchBar to be hidden override UITableView and call hideSearchBar when tableview is initially loaded for the first time.

Comment: sorry but u r wrong, the search bar is the table view header view, you can just print self.tableView.tableHeaderView and see. the tableHeadrView is also a subview of the tableView so of course you will see it when printing all the subviews... anyway I prefer not to use your approach, cause adding the search bar to a cell is not an ideal solution here.

Comment: @Eyal you are right. However, my solutions is simple , ideal or not is your choice.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is a little stupid.

Add this method to the sample code.

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
    [self hideSearchBar];
}
```

It seems the tableView will redraw the scrollView inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Since the tableView reset the contentOffset, I made a custom tableView has property to save the hidden status of search bar.Below is the code.Hope it helps.

```
//
//  TableViewController.m
//  SearchBarJump
//
//  Created by Eyal Cohen on 3/9/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Eyal. All rights reserved.
//

#import "TableViewController.h"


@interface CustomTableView : UITableView

@property (nonatomic, assign, getter = isSearchBarHidden)BOOL searchBarHidden;

@end

@implementation CustomTableView

@synthesize searchBarHidden = _searchBarHidden;

- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    if (self.isSearchBarHidden) {
        [self hideSearchBar:NO];
    }
}

- (void)setSearchBarHidden:(BOOL)searchBarHidden
{
    _searchBarHidden = searchBarHidden;
    if (_searchBarHidden && self.contentOffset.y != self.tableHeaderView.frame.size.height) {
        [self hideSearchBar:YES];
    }
}

- (void)hideSearchBar:(BOOL)animated {
    // hide search bar
    [self setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0.0, self.tableHeaderView.frame.size.height) animated:animated];
}

@end

@interface TableViewController () {
    NSInteger _rows;
}

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet CustomTableView *mainTable;

@end

@implementation TableViewController

@synthesize mainTable = _mainTable;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.view = _mainTable;
    [_mainTable setDelegate:self];
    [_mainTable setDataSource:self];

    _rows = 3;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.mainTable setSearchBarHidden:YES];
}


- (void)hideSearchBar {
    // hide search bar
    [_mainTable setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0.0, self.tableView.tableHeaderView.frame.size.height) animated:NO];
}

- (IBAction)toggleCount:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {
    if (_rows == 20) {
        _rows = 3;
    } else {
        _rows = 20;
    }
    [_mainTable reloadData];
}

- (IBAction)hideBar:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {
    [self hideSearchBar];
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return _rows;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.textLabel.text = @"cell";

    return cell;
}
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    [_mainTable setSearchBarHidden:NO];
}
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if (_mainTable.contentOffset.y == _mainTable.tableHeaderView.bounds.size.height) {
        [_mainTable setSearchBarHidden:YES];
    }
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

I fix the bug just like this:

```
@interface NTTableView : UITableView
@end

@implementation NTTableView

-(void)setContentOffset:(CGPoint)contentOffset{
if (self.contentOffset.y==-20&&
    contentOffset.y==-64) {
    NSLog(@"iOS7 bug here, FML");
}else{
    [super setContentOffset:contentOffset];
 }
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix for my somewhat similar situation with a `UISearchBar` as the `tableHeaderView`. Not sure if this falls into the same exact scenario, but it hides the search bar when the view appears. (Being unconcerned with the amount of rows in the table view)

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting `edgesForExtendedLayout` to `[.top, .bottom]` instead of just `.top` on **TVC** fixed problem for me.

Of course, `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` is set to `false`
**EDIT:** seems that it only works if tvc.tabBar is `translucent`

Answer (score -1):

As a weird hack I can only suggest to add an empty cell to the end of cells with height about 400

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
// Return the number of rows in the section.
return _rows + 1;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

if(indexPath.row == _rows)
{
    //cellEmpty - cell identifier in storyboard
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cellEmpty" forIndexPath:indexPath];
}
else
{
    cell.textLabel.text = @"cell";

}

// Configure the cell...

return cell;
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if(indexPath.row == _rows)
{
    return 400;
}
else
{
    return 44;
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

your output file

https://github.com/iDevAndroid/SearchBarJump

simply use this code don't make do complex for that

```
-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated{

    [self.tableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(-0.3, 0, 0, 0)];

    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}
```

here is one problem if you are set UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0) the searchBar jumping as in original mode