# How to customize the top bar of a UINavigationController with the current view information?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios

I've a UINavigationController and in the picture you can see a UIViewController added to it.

Now, I would like to customize the top bar of the UINavigationController with the content of the current visible UIViewController. More in particular, I would like:

1. add the title
2. customize "back" button text

Should I use self.navigationController method from the current UINavigationController ? If so, what are the next steps ?

Thanks
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the Title with:

```
[[self navigationItem] setTitle:@"title text"];
```

You can change the backbuttontext in the InterfaceBuilder or:

```
[[[self navigationItem] backBarButtonItem] setTitle:@"back button text"];
```

But remember that the backBarButtonItem comes from the previous ViewController so you have to set it there. Alternatively the title is set from the previous view.

Comment: I've found out that it doesn't work in viewWillAppear but only in viewDidLoad. Since my view is appearing, why can't I set it there ? thanks

Comment: Actually what you say for the button is not correct. I need to replace the button instead of the text to make it work. i.e. https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2508892?threadID=2508892

Comment: are you sure that viewWillAppear is called? I tested only with viewDidLoad. But sometimes there are problems with viewWillAppear ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/131062/iphone-viewwillappear-not-firing ). I tested my code on a sample project and it was working fine. So I'm sure my code is right.

Answer (score 0):

```
self.title = "Your title";
```

You can use this in the current view controller for displaying title