# viewWillAppear is never called

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, viewwillappear

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iphone viewWillAppear not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/131062/iphone-viewwillappear-not-firing)

I have a problem, I have a tabBar / NavigationBar application. I try to use viewWillAppear but nothing.  If I put a simple NSLog the console not show. Where is the problem?

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        [self readArgFromDatabaseSottoArgomenti];
        [self VisualizzaPreferiti];

    }

    - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

NSLog(@"test");

        [self VisualizzaPreferiti];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }

    -(void) readArgFromDatabaseSottoArgomenti {

        databasePath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ARGOMENTI.sqlite"];

        sqlite3 *databaseDesc;
        // Init the argoments Array
        arraySottoArgomenti = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        // Open the database from the users filessytem
        if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &databaseDesc) == SQLITE_OK) {
            // Setup the SQL Statement and compile it for faster access
            // const char *sqlStatement = "select * from DESCRIZIONE ";
            const char *sqlStatement = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * from DESCRIZIONE ORDER BY id"] UTF8String];
            sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
            if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(databaseDesc, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
                // Loop through the results and add them to the feeds array
                while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                    // Read the data from the result row
                    NSString *aID = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 0)];
                    NSString *aIDArgomento = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)];
                    NSString *aDescrizione = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 2)];
                    NSString *aTesto = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 3)];

                    // Create a new argoments object with the data from the database
                    ContenutoObjectDescrizione *contenutoSottoArgomenti = [[ContenutoObjectDescrizione alloc] initWithName:aID idArgomento:aIDArgomento descrizione:aDescrizione testo:aTesto];
                    [arraySottoArgomenti addObject:contenutoSottoArgomenti];

                    [contenutoSottoArgomenti release];
                }
            }


            // Release the compiled statement from memory
            sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);

        }
        sqlite3_close(databaseDesc);

    }

    - (void) VisualizzaPreferiti {

        int i;

        NSUserDefaults *userPref = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        array = [userPref objectForKey:@"array"];


        NSLog(@"Retain Count %d Numero ID Array %d",[array retainCount],[array count]);



        NSMutableArray *arrayOggettoPreferito;
        arrayOggettoPreferito = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        ContenutoObjectDescrizione *oggetto = [[ContenutoObjectDescrizione alloc] init];

        for (oggetto in arraySottoArgomenti) {
            for (i=0; i<[array count]; i++) {

                if ([[array objectAtIndex:i] intValue] == [oggetto.id intValue]) {
                    [arrayOggettoPreferito addObject:oggetto];

                    NSLog(@"ID %@ IDMateria %@ Titolo %@",oggetto.id,oggetto.idArgomento,oggetto.descrizione);
                }
            }
        }   

        listaPref = arrayOggettoPreferito;

        arrayOggettoPreferito=nil;
        [arrayOggettoPreferito release];
        [oggetto release];  

    }

    #pragma mark -
    #pragma mark Table view data source

    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
        // Return the number of sections.
        return 1;
    }


    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
        // Return the number of rows in the section.
        return [listaPref count];
    }


    // Customize the appearance of table view cells.
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        }

        ContenutoObjectDescrizione *oggettoCercato = [[ContenutoObjectDescrizione alloc] init];
        oggettoCercato = [listaPref objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

        cell.textLabel.text = oggettoCercato.descrizione;
        NSLog(@"%@",oggettoCercato.descrizione);


        return cell;
    }

    #pragma mark -
    #pragma mark Table view delegate

    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

        TestoViewController *testoViewController = [[TestoViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TestoView" bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:testoViewController animated:YES];

        ContenutoObjectDescrizione *oggettoCercato = [[ContenutoObjectDescrizione alloc] init];
        oggettoCercato = [listaPref objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

        testoViewController.idPreferito = oggettoCercato.id;

        testoViewController.title = oggettoCercato.descrizione;

        NSString *descrizioneWeb = oggettoCercato.testo;

        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
        NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

        [testoViewController.vistaWeb loadHTMLString:descrizioneWeb baseURL:baseURL];
        [testoViewController release];


    }

    #pragma mark -
    #pragma mark Memory management

    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
        // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
        [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

        // Relinquish ownership any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
    }

    - (void)viewDidUnload {
        // Relinquish ownership of anything that can be recreated in viewDidLoad or on demand.
        // For example: self.myOutlet = nil;
    }


    - (void)dealloc {
        [sup

er dealloc];
}
```

Comment: At this moment, none of this code is relevant. You will have to provide info/code about how you push this table view controller onto the screen.

Comment: I have a tabBar, for every Tab I set a controller (with a nib) in Interface Builder. Now I read the link!

Answer (score 0):

Add `[super viewWillAppear];` and give it a try.