# viewDidDisapper won't call

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have uinavigation controller with a view controller named VC1,now i have a button in VC1 that when i click on him i go to view controller VC2,this is how i bring VC2 to screen :

```
VC2 *tmp = [[VC2 alloc]init];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:tmp animated:YES];
[tmp release];
```

now when i click in VC2 on the back button of the navigation to return to VC1 its work but i put in VC2 viewDidDisappear and viewWillDisappear methods,and when i click on the back button this function won't called, any one have any idea?

Comment: How do you know that these methods aren't called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *may* call the view[..] methods manually from the `UINavigationControllerDelegate` callbacks, however the easiest way to ensure that the methods are called by the super implementation of the `UINavigationController` is just to call them manually once when the `UINavigationController` is allocated.

See my answer here: [iPhone viewWillAppear not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/131062/iphone-viewwillappear-not-firing/6833875#6833875)

So immediately after you have called `navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init..`, make sure to call

```
[navController viewWillAppear:NO];
[navController viewDidAppear:NO];
[navController viewWillDisappear:NO];
[navController viewDidDisappear:NO];
```

This should ensure events are correctly forwarded to each view controller in the future.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to call the viewWillDisappear/viewDidDisappear methods, your view controller has to do that manually before popping itself off the nav stack. Have a look at [this](http://cocoa.agilemonks.com/2011/02/19/uinavigationcontroller-doesnt-call-viewwillappear-or-viewwilldisappear/)
,you might get an idea how to do it.

Comment: I think this isn't true. I have a navigationController and a viewController which is popped from the nav stack and viewWillDisappear is called every time.