# -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated doesn't called

Tags: objective-c

My application is view based in my app in one view i write view will appear but this method doesn't call. My code is

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSLog(@"view will Appear");
    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

Can anyone tell why viewWillAppear method not called.

Sorry I forgot To tell You That This method call first time but when i remove a subview from this view viewWillAppear not called. Please Suggest me how to solve this problem.

Comment: try to have a look at this this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/131062/iphone-viewwillappear-not-firing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Here I did instead

```
[self.view addSubview:viewcontroller.view];
```

I Used this:

```
[self presentModalViewController:viewcontroller animated:YES];
```

and write this method now my problem is solved.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSLog(@"==========view will appear");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated  
{  
  [super viewWillAppear:animated];  
  NSLog(@"view will Appear");    
  [tableView reloadData];  
}
```

if still it is not calling then try to call through code , as per example [classobj viewWillAppear:NO];

Comment: Thanks but My problem is not solve viewWillAppear method not calling.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/131062/iphone-viewwillappear-not-firing

Answer (score 0):

The viewWillAppear and other related methods are called to the viewcontroller that are linked with the rootViewController of the mainWindow.
So if you are using a view based application, the viewWillAppear method of the first view controller will work properly and others wont.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem you are seeing is that `viewWillAppear:` is a method on a `UIViewController`, and not a method on `UIView`.  `viewWillAppear:` is called on the view controller to indicate that the controller's view will become visible.

If you have added the code above to a class based on `UIView`, that code won't get called.  You need to move that code to your view controller -or- you might achieve the result that you are looking for by implementing the `didMoveToSuperview` method in your UIView based class instead.

`didMoveToSuperview` will be called on your view when your view is added to another view using `addSubview:`.