# iOS - UITextView becomeFirstResponder

Tags: ios, uitextview, becomefirstresponder

This is the problem : when MessageComposeViewController has been dismissed, my textView doesn't become the first responder and the keyboard doesn't appear. Why? I put the `[textView becomeFirstResponder]` code in `viewWillAppear`. How can i do??

Comment: A couple standard questions:  does `viewWillAppear` get called after  MessageComposeViewController is dismissed?  is textView not null?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann textView isn't null, i'm sure, but how can i know if viewWillAppear is called after the message controller is dismissed?

Comment: set a breakpoint and see if it hits.

Comment: Or add `NSLog(@"foo")` (but see my answer below)

Comment: @jon the nslog print the correct values

Comment: @MichaelDautermann where would i set a breakpoint? on viewWillAppear?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the solution!!!!!!!!
So, in the `messageComposeViewController:didFinishWithResult` delegate method we call `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]`, but it's wrong! This method should receive NO, not YES! And then recall the `[textView becomeFirstResponder]` method! I don't know why, but in this way the app works perfectly!
Thanks all however! :)

Comment: Comments as to why this is marked down would be lovely.

Comment: Only thing I could think of is using viewDidAppear, so it happens in correct order.

Answer (score 5):

I called becomeFirstResponder later by this line:

```
[self.searchBar performSelector:@selector(becomeFirstResponder) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1f];
```

It worked for me. Hope this help.

I guess it's the animation's reason.

Comment: I also had issues with the view getting covered up if I called becomeFirstResponder too quickly.  I changed the delay to 0.0f and called the line above in viewDidAppear and that sorted things out.  Seems like it gets confused if it's called while things are still changing.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Note from the [official Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/event_delivery_responder_chain/event_delivery_responder_chain.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH4-SW1) :

> Make sure that your app has established its object graph before assigning an object to be the first responder. For example, you typically call the becomeFirstResponder method in an override of the viewDidAppear: method. If you try to assign the first responder in viewWillAppear:, your object graph is not yet established, so the becomeFirstResponder method returns NO.

you should call `[textView becomeFirstResponder]` in the `viewDidAppear:` instead of `viewWillAppear:`.

Seems the solution you have found with `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO]` is utilizing the same rule from the note.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't particularly clear, but you have assumed that `viewWillAppear` is called when a modal view controller (what I assume you have called *MessageComposeViewController*) is dismissed. This may not be the case under all cirumstances (e.g. if your view is inside a `UINavigationController`)

There are a number of ways you could handle this, but perhaps the simplest would be to pass your *MessageComposeViewController* a reference to your original view controller and call a method to make your `UITextField` the first responder.

Comment: I thought viewWillAppear is called when the modal view is dismissed. I don't understand what do you mean when you say to pass a reference to MessageComposeViewController. How can i do this?

Comment: Have a look at this question for examples of where `viewWillAppear` might and might not be called: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/131062/iphone-viewwillappear-not-firing

If none of those work, then I can provide some code examples but the easiest would be to create an instance variable and property on MessageComposeViewController which after initialisation is given a reference back to the original view controller.

Comment: MessageViewController is a default controller, how can i create a property on it?

Answer (score 0):

I have more or less the same problem, it was related with animation at the segue, it looks like doing a segue o dismiss a view without using the resignFirstResponder break the relation with the view, I just modify the segue to doing it programatically like this:

```
  - (IBAction)back:(id)sender {

     [textView resignFirstResponder];
     [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"returnScreen" sender:self];
  }
```

An then in the viewWillAppear I did the next:

```
 -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
     [super viewWillAppear:animated];
     [textView becomeFirstResponder];

  ....

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In swift

```
let when = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(0.1 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
    dispatch_after(when, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        self.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
```