# How do you access another UIViewController in appDelegate when login using facebook-ios-sdk?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, delegates, facebook-ios-sdk

**answer:**

Finally I use Notifications that I think is a elegant way to do it.

Thanks you Alan.

---

I have a facebook login (through facebook-ios-sdk) in my tab based app.

I initial "Facebook" in my appDelegate.

I have a "Connect Facebook" UIButton in settingViewController Tab.

I can login facebook through clicking the "Connect Facebook" UIButton (in settingViewController Tab), and then "- (void)fbDidLogin" (in appDelegate) get called.

Everything is fine.

But my question is how to update "Connect Facebook" UIButton (in settingViewController Tab) to "Facebook connected"?

Can I do something like this in appDelegate:

```
- (void)fbDidLogin 
{
    NSUserDefaults * userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [userDefaults setObject:[self.facebook accessToken] forKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
    [userDefaults setObject:[self.facebook expirationDate] forKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
    [userDefaults synchronize];

    if (settingViewController) {
        settingViewController.facebookButton.text = @"facebook connected";
    }
}
```

Thanks you.

---

What I have tried:

I put this in settingViewController Tab, but this was not called when the app return from the facebook login screen. So I guess I may have to use delegate in "- (void)fbDidLogin" in appDelegate?

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [self checkAccStatusAndUpdateButton];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways you could deal with this.  Here are a couple:

**NSUserDefaults**
You could store a flag in `NSUserDefaults` when Facebook is connected.  In the `viewDidLoad` method of `SettingViewController` you could check that flag and make the appropriate change in your `UIButton` title.

**Notifications**
In the `fbDidLogin` method, you could fire an `NSNotification`; and your `SettingViewController` could observe that notification and change the button title.  That approach assumes `SettingViewController` instance exists and can observe the notification.

Comment: Thanks @alan, I do use NSUserDefaults but I dont know how to make SettingViewController check it after returning from facebook login, since - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated wont be triggered. (why)

Comment: It depends on how your view hierarchy is constructed.  It sounds like you have a `UITabBarController` ...  In its `tabBarController:didSelectViewController` delegate method, you could propagate the FB flag setting to the `SettingViewController`.  For more info on when `viewWillAppear` is called, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/131062/iphone-viewwillappear-not-firing)