# didUpdateUserLocation not getting called re loading the view

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview

I have a mapViewController (in a Navigation Controller). When I open it for the first time, after viewDidLoad, `- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation` gets called.

When I go back to the previous viewController and come again to the mapViewController, the didUpdateUserLocation delegate is not being called, hence my annotations are not getting shown.

Please help me in finding the solution to the problem. Thank you.

Comment: Where are you setting your delegate? Have you confirmed that your delegate is being properly set?

Comment: @iWasRobbed: in viewDidLoad I am setting my delegate like this
`self.mapView.delegate = self;`

Is there anything wrong?

Comment: If you're also setting the delegate in a different view controller, the `viewDidLoad` method might not be called again if you immediately come back to a view that you just dismissed.  Try setting it in the `viewWillAppear` method instead

Comment: @iWasRobbed: Tried what you said, but still the didUpdateUserLocation not being called when coming back to mapView. In fact I noticed that my viewWillAppear is not even getting called once.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the map view to continue to track the user’s location and update it periodically, you should set MapView `showsUserLocation` to YES (the default value is NO).

Try

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated 
{    
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    ...
    [mapView setShowsUserLocation: YES];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated 
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    ...
    [mapView setShowsUserLocation: NO];
}
```

Apple Doc: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html

Comment: regarding your problem with the `viewWillAppear`, [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/131062/iphone-viewwillappear-not-firing)

Answer (score -1):

Call this method in - view will appear method of same class

```
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

Comment: Not working. Actually my viewWillAppear is not getting called too. Any idea?