# xcode alertView tutorial returns blank on the simulator

Tags: uialertview

new to xcode and obj-c, i spend two day trying to solve this!

here's my alertViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface alert_ViewController : UIViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate>
@end
```

my alertViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
@implementation alert_ViewController

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    NSString *message = @"Are you sure?";
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                              initWithTitle: @"Proceed?"
                              message:message
                              delegate:self
                              cancelButtonTitle: @"No"
                              otherButtonTitles: @"Yes", nil];
    [alertView show];
}
@end
```

i run the project on the simulator and it comes up blank. any ideas?
thank you

Comment: Could you post the link to tutorial?

Comment: the tutorial was for xcode 4, and this is just a snip from it. my problem is why does viewDidAppear never gets called? is my code in the wrong place?

Comment: That is strange. Will need to see the rest of the code to make a comment on that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone viewWillAppear not firing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/131062/iphone-viewwillappear-not-firing)