# present ViewController calling viewWillDisappear but does not call viewWillAppear

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, presentviewcontroller, viewwillappear, viewwilldisappear

Following is my code present safari view controller

```
 if let url = URL(string: "https://www.ggogle.com.com/") {
            let config = SFSafariViewController.Configuration()
            config.entersReaderIfAvailable = true
            let vc = SFSafariViewController(url: url, configuration: config)
            present(vc, animated: false)


        }
```

Above code calls viewWillDisappear but does not call viewWillAppear when presented view controller is dismissed.

**Also found that after view is dismissed viewWillDisappear is not called at all for any other pushViewController**

How to fix this?

**Update on this:**

Tried navigation controller and set its delegate and implemented following methods

```
navigationController:willShowViewController:animated:
navigationController:didShowViewController:animated:
```

This is not working as well.

Update on this tried following code

```
  vc.modalPresentationStyle = .currentContext
```

But using this tab bar does not hides and controller not appearing full screen and there is no option like hide bottom bar on present.

Comment: Parent's ViewWillAppear not called when a view controller is dismissed. What we can do either use delegate or completion of dismiss method.

Comment: updated question Also found that after view is dismissed viewWillDisappear is not called at all for any other pushViewController

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/131062/iphone-viewwillappear-not-firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/131062/iphone-viewwillappear-not-firing) A good read.

Comment: dimissing a controller will not call viewWillappear of dimissed controller, but it will call viewWillAppear of controller that is going to display after dismissed controller.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
 if let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com/") {
            let config = SFSafariViewController.Configuration()
            config.entersReaderIfAvailable = true
            let vc = SFSafariViewController(url: url, configuration: config)

            vc.modalPresentationStyle = .currentContext

            present(vc, animated: false)

        }
```

**UPDATE**

```
vc.modalPresentationStyle = .currentContext
tabBarController?.present(viewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

Comment: This is causing issue as well this does not hide tabbar